# Accessing raw ActiveRecord data for Rails migration

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'd like to migrate some of the columns of my user table into a separate related table.  A few of these columns use ActiveRecord's `serialize` functionality to store hash and set data in a single column.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  serialize :foo, Hash
  ...
end
```

I'd like to move that column (in addition to many others) into a separate table:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  serialize :foo, Hash

  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

As part of the migration I copy over a bunch of user attributes into the profile before dropping the user columns.  The problem is when I read `user.foo` the data is no longer deserialized.  So when I set `profile.foo = user.foo` I get an error: `Attribute was supposed to be a Hash, but was a String`.

Is there a way to copy the raw database values during the migration or do I need to perform my own deserialization in this case?

Thanks!

EDIT: Adding migration

```
class CreateProfile < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :profiles do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.text :foo

      # A bunch of other fields
    end

    User.all.find_each do |user|
      params = { user: user }

      # Copy all fields here
      params[:foo] = user[:foo]
      ...

      profile = Profile.new(params)
      profile.save!
    end

    # Remove a bunch of fields
    remove_column :users, :foo
    ...
  end

  ...
end
```

Comment: post your migration code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could execute raw sql in migration which will be the fastest if you have large number of user records

```
execute("INSERT INTO profiles(user_id, foo) SELECT id, foo FROM users")
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are removing the `serialize :foo, Hash` line in your `User` model with the anticipation that this column will be dropped.  Because of this, you run into the problem you described.  You can either:

- Leave that line in place and remove it at a later point after all migrations have run.  And that means *all* migrations for *all* existing environments for your codebase (or they will later break as @scttnlsn has pointed out).  A much simpler approach would be...
- Use a SQL 'UPDATE' statement to copy the data:

Assuming you have created the profiles in advance, you can update them like so:

```
execute("UPDATE profiles SET foo = users.foo FROM users WHERE user_id = users.id")
```

If you are creating these profile records on the fly during this migration, use an INSERT query similar to the one that @Vimsha has proposed.

Comment: The first option you mention would make the migrations break in the future (since it requires `serialize :foo, Hash` in the user model).

Comment: Right, that's why this should not be removed until after _all_ migrations have been run for _all_ existing environments.  Newly created db's in the future would be able to derive from schema.rb and wouldn't be affected by this.  I do agree that because of this wrinkle the SQL approach would be preferred, but not all developers want to go the SQL route...

Comment: Yeah, I think SQL makes the most sense.  I'll probably take an approach like @Vimsha mentions.